# Yarn Spark HBase - ExecutorLostFailure Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to read a big hbase table in spark (~100GB in size).

Spark Version : 1.6

Spark submit parameters:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --num-executors 10  --executor-memory 4G 
             --executor-cores 4 
             --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048
```

> Error: ExecutorLostFailure Reason: Container killed by YARN for
>   exceeding limits. 
>   4.5GB of 3GB physical memory used limits. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.

I have tried setting `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` to `100000`. Still getting similar error.

I don't understand why spark doesn't spill to disk if the memory is insufficient OR is YARN causing the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code how you try to read in.
And also your cluster architecture

> Container killed by YARN for exceeding limits. 4.5GB of 3GB physical memory used limits

Try

```
spark-submit 
--master yarn-client 
--num-executors 4  
--executor-memory 100G
--executor-cores 4 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=20480
```

If you have 128 gRam

The situation is clear, you run out of ram, try to rewrite your code in a disk friendly way.